# Использование json.loads в python

Tags: python, python-3.x, json

Как из этого `json` получить данные со строки `i_market_hash_name` через `json.loads`?

Возможно, есть другие способы?

```
{
    "type": "newitems_go",
    "data":"{\"i_quality\":\"\\u041f\\u0440\\u044f\\u043c\\u043e \\u0441 \\u0437\\u0430\\u0432\\u043e\\u0434\\u0430\",\"i_name_color\":\"D2D2D2\",\"i_classid\":\"992122820\",\"i_instanceid\":\"519977179\",\"i_market_hash_name\":\"Dual Berettas | Moon in Libra (Factory New)\",\"i_market_name\":\"Dual Berettas | \\u041b\\u0443\\u043d\\u0430 \\u0432 \\u0437\\u043d\\u0430\\u043a\\u0435 \\u0412\\u0435\\u0441\\u043e\\u0432 (\\u041f\\u0440\\u044f\\u043c\\u043e \\u0441 \\u0437\\u0430\\u0432\\u043e\\u0434\\u0430)\",\"ui_price\":50.79,\"ui_currency\":\"RUB\",\"app\":\"go\"}"}
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import json
    
my_json1 = {"type":"newitems_go","data":"{\"i_quality\":\"\\u041f\\u0440\\u044f\\u043c\\u043e \\u0441 \\u0437\\u0430\\u0432\\u043e\\u0434\\u0430\",\"i_name_color\":\"D2D2D2\",\"i_classid\":\"992122820\",\"i_instanceid\":\"519977179\",\"i_market_hash_name\":\"Dual Berettas | Moon in Libra (Factory New)\",\"i_market_name\":\"Dual Berettas | \\u041b\\u0443\\u043d\\u0430 \\u0432 \\u0437\\u043d\\u0430\\u043a\\u0435 \\u0412\\u0435\\u0441\\u043e\\u0432 (\\u041f\\u0440\\u044f\\u043c\\u043e \\u0441 \\u0437\\u0430\\u0432\\u043e\\u0434\\u0430)\",\"ui_price\":50.79,\"ui_currency\":\"RUB\",\"app\":\"go\"}"}
my_json2 = json.loads(my_json1['data'])

result = my_json2['i_market_hash_name']
```

```
>>> print(result)
Dual Berettas | Moon in Libra (Factory New)
```